# Working With SmartSheets API, Loop Through List for Variable of a Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartsheet-api

I have a list of numbers like below stored into a variable.

```
[700000000084,
100000000051652,
8800000000000072,
280000000000004,
680000000000008,
880000000000006]
```

I am trying to loop this through the SmartSheets API to pull all the info I need into one block of data.

```
var options = {
  id: 8800000000000072 // ID of Sheet
};

// Get sheet as CSV.
smartsheet.sheets.getSheetAsCSV(options)
  .then(function(data) 
  {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) 
  {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

What would be the most efficient way to loop the list into

```
var options = 
{
  id: IDLoop // ID of Sheet
};
```

All the while, when the new number is in the options parameters to run the function and collect the data, I need to do this with all the numbers in the list and collect all of the data it produces.

Any advice to the most efficient way to do this?
I am assuming I will need to do some sort of loop, but any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a for loop like this?

```js
var options = [700000000084,
100000000051652,
8800000000000072,
280000000000004,
680000000000008,
880000000000006]

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

 // Get sheet as CSV.
 smartsheet.sheets.getSheetAsCSV(options[i])
   .then(function(data) 
   {
     console.log(data);
   })
   .catch(function(error) 
   {
     console.log(error);
   });

}
```

Comment: I get an error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetAsCSV' of undefined

Comment: I actually got it to work. I have accepted your answer. Thank you so much for the help.